# Laravel 8.0.3 - Can't get data from the database

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get the data from the `posts` table but I get an error message:

**PostsController.php**
<?php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function show( $slug ) {        
        $posts = DB::table('posts')->get();
        dd($posts);
    }
}
```

**.env file**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

**but I get this error:**

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `posts`)

**Url I am trying to access:**

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/first-post

**See the shareable laravel error message:**

https://flareapp.io/share/xPQr0171#F54

**Update:**

Error message I get after running `php artisan migrate`

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
    667▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 671▕             throw new QueryException(
    672▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673▕             );
    674▕         }
    675▕ 

      +37 vendor frames 
  38  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

**Raw Code**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=laravel", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "Connected successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Does your credentials work if you try them using PhpMyAdmin or HeidiSQL or MySqlWorkbenck or anything else ?

Comment: I have checked the connection with raw code. It's working there.

Comment: why people are providing negative marking ??? I am new at laravel.

Comment: Do you have the right PDO extensions enabled in PHP?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled.

Comment: I just want to get the data from the `posts` table. I have created that table manually.

Comment: does `php artisan migrate` work ?

Comment: I don't have any migration files created. I just created the table manually from PHPMyAdmin

Comment: Yes, but `Laravel` got some by default if you did remove them.

Comment: Oh, I see some error message :(

Comment: I have updated the error message. Please check

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58658735/laravel-6-4-1-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused

Comment: @creativeartbd please post the raw code with which you tested the raw connection.

Answer (score 1):

Can you test that :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function show( $slug ) {
        return response()->json(
            config("database.connections.mysql.database"),
            200
        );
    }
}
```

It should show your database name (laravel).
If it's not, your `.env` file is invalid.

Comment: I have solved the issues. It's all about MySQL port issue